# Regular Expressions, using search in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to decode a some hex in python.

In part of the string `\xcd\xed\xb0\xb2`

```
    text = re.search(r'(\\x\w{2}){4}', rtf)

    unicodeText = text.decode('gb2312')
```

Error: **'_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'decode'**

Hope someone can help, Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? Can't you decode the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects), not a matched string.

Use [`group`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) method to get the matched string.

```
>>> rtf = r'\xcd\xed\xb0\xb2'
>>> matched = re.search(r'(\\x\w{2}){4}', rtf)
>>> text = matched.group()
>>> text.decode('string-escape').decode('gb2312')
u'\u665a\u5b89'

# In Python 3.x
# >>> text.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
# '晚安'
```

---

BTW, you don't need to use regular expression, what you want is convert `\xOO`:

Python 2.x:

```
>>> rtf = r'\xcd\xed\xb0\xb2'
>>> rtf.decode('string-escape').decode('gb2312')
u'\u665a\u5b89'
>>> print rtf.decode('string-escape').decode('gb2312')
晚安
```

Python 3.x:

```
>>> rtf = r'\xcd\xed\xb0\xb2'
>>> rtf.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
'晚安'
```

Comment: That returns "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: @JamesGarner, I just updated the answer. If you use Python 3.x, try the code in the comment.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I will mark correct as soon as I can

Comment: @JamesGarner, I updated the answer again. In short, you don't need to use regular expression.

Comment: The reason why I use the regex is because I have mulitple languages, should it not matter?

Comment: @JamesGarner, Do you mean text encoded with multiple encoding?

Comment: @JamesGarner, Try just the last part as I show in the answer. And if it works, no need to worry.

Comment: Yes exactly because I'm taking it all from a RTF string